# How to verify special values in C++

Tags: c++, nan

If in C++ I got the any of the following values, how to verify or compare them?

```
float pinf = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
double dpinf = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();

float ninf = -std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
float NaN = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
float nNaN = -std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
double dNaN = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "verify"? What do you want to know?

Comment: by "veryfy" I mean whether there is a simple function to check the current special value status for : ` not a number`, `infinity`, `indetermine` and so on.

Comment: You're missing a few `const`s.

Comment: For example, `isnan()` for `not a number`, `isinf()` for `infinity`, and `isind()` for `indetermine`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`std::fpclassify`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fpclassify) or any of the related functions.

Comment: Nice, I've never seen that function before.

Comment: So this is C++ 11 features? I have only VC++ 10.0

Comment: @LCFactorization: There are related functions in the C standard library; see the linked documentation. Those might be available to you.

Comment: would you please add a simple example into the answer?

Comment: @LCFactorization: Like `assert(!std::isnan(x))`?

Comment: Thank you. I am a beginner. is there any further details? for example, is this C++98 feature? which header should I include? Can you also show it for `inf` and `indetermine`?